# button onclick document instead using in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, dom, button, onclick

I have some issue which i need to write in js file instead of button on-click someone help me please. I written some code but its not working properly.

**Thanks**

```js
document.getElementById("box1").onclick = function (box) {
    box.style.display = 'block';
};
```

```css
#box1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 260px;
    height: 260px;
    background: #E2E2E2;
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul onclick="document.getElementById('box1').style.display='block'"  class="btn-menu">pop-out Interface</ul>
<h2>More Page Content...</h2>
    <ul  id="box1">
        <li><a href="#" >Homes</a></li>
    </ul>
<h2>
```

Comment: You need to describe in better detail what you're trying to do. What element are you clicking? What element is meant to be displayed? Because, atm, it looks like you're trying to click a hidden element to show it...?

Comment: Hello Andy, What i need, I just need that click action in js file which they working on button html but i wanna using that code into js file example (var document.getElementById like this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that will toggle a panel off/on when you click a menu button. Hope it helps you out. It uses a data-attribute to coordinate what menu button reveals which panel.

```js
// grab all the menu buttons
const menuButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-menu');

// attach a click event to each button
menuButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', toggleButton, false));

function toggleButton() {

  // get the data-id from the clicked element
  const id = this.dataset.id;

  // pick up the panel element with that id
  const panel = document.getElementById(id);
  if (panel.style.display === 'block') {
    panel.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    panel.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
.panel {
  top: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #E2E2E2;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul data-id="box1" class="btn-menu">pop-out Interface</ul>
<ul data-id="box2" class="btn-menu">pop-out Interface 2</ul>
<h2>More Page Content...</h2>
<ul id="box1" class="panel">
  <li><a href="#">Homes</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="box2" class="panel">
  <li><a href="#">Gardens</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This what i have been Triying it. But code is too long, when you see in the html its very simple ? but anyway Thanks Mate.

Comment: It's a bit longer because of the condition to toggle between the two states which you didn't have before, and it doesn't use inline JS. This also assumes that you have more than one button/panel and will work for those too.

Comment: I've updated the HTML to show you how it works with more than one button @sai

Comment: Thanks Andy. I will try it sure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to migrate your js code to its own file to be able to toggle your elements display.

The elements onclick method takes in a function to execute when the event is triggered. What we will have to do is build a function in a JS file, import that file into our markup, and then we can reference our new function in our markup in the elements onclick.

```js
function showBox(){           
    document.getElementById("box1")style.display = 'block';
}

function hideBox(){           
    document.getElementById("box1")style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
     #box1 {
            
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            width: 260px;
            height: 260px;
            background: #E2E2E2;
            padding: 20px;
            display: none;
            
        }
```

```html
<script src="/path/to/lang-js.js" />

<ul onclick="showBox()" class="btn-menu">pop-out Interface</ul>
        <h2>More Page Content...</h2>
          <ul  id="box1">
            <li><a href="#" >Homes</a></li>
```